# How to select just current month data in SQL?

Tags: sql, subquery, date-arithmetic

I'm trying to make a query that makes me able to select just the data from the current month from a table, the date field that I'm using as reference is Datetime Type (e.g 2021-02-19 03:23:31), this field is called "Date". My try is this as follow:

```
Select * 
FROM CORP.T_LOGI_RN_Planeacion_Entregas 
Where Cast(CORP.T_LOGI_RN_Planeacion_Entregas.Date As Date) >= Cast(Month(getdate()) As Date)
```

It's not working, (im not pretty sure if I need to use "Cast" Actually) it throws me this error:

***Cannot cast type int to date***

But using something like this where I'm not specifying the Month, it works:

```
Select * 
FROM CORP.T_LOGI_RN_Planeacion_Entregas 
Where Cast(CORP.T_LOGI_RN_Planeacion_Entregas.Date As Date) >= Cast(getdate() As Date)
```

Any idea?

Thanks by the way and sorry if the solution is so obvious I'm little bit new on this, best regards.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have not specified your DB Product but from your syntax It seems SQL Server. YOu can use MONTH function here -

```
Select *
FROM CORP.T_LOGI_RN_Planeacion_Entregas
Where MONTH(CORP.T_LOGI_RN_Planeacion_Entregas.Date) = MONTH(GETDATE())
  AND YEAR(CORP.T_LOGI_RN_Planeacion_Entregas.Date) = YEAR(GETDATE());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ankit Bajpai Actually I just  solved the problem making exactly what you recommend me, curious because was a second before got your answer, but yeah! you were right

Comment: Generally you want to make a similar connection on `YEAR(getdate())` too, as otherwise you get that month from all years for which you have data.

Comment: @SteveLovell, Completely agree and corrected.